# When deserializing JSON, How can I configure the concrete type used for properties declared as IList<T> to be ObservableCollection<T>?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, observablecollection, system.text.json

I have some classes that model the structure I expect from my JSON file. For values that are an array in the JSON, the corresponding C# properties are declared to have the type `IList<T>` for various types `T`. I do not control these classes. When deserializing the JSON into the root type `MyClass`, how can I make it so that all properties of the classes that I get back of type `IList<T>` are constructed using the concrete type `ObservableCollection<T>`? Please note that `MyClass` has deeply nested properties of type `IList<T>`.

Hopefully the following example shows my intentions a bit more clearly:

```
class MyClass{
    public IList<NestedClass> MyList { get; set; }
}

class NestedClass{
    public IList<AnotherNestedClass> NestedList { get; set; }
}

class AnotherNestedClass{
    // ... various properties.
}
```

```
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jsonString);
Console.WriteLine(obj?.MyList?.GetType()); // This should be ObservableCollection<NestedClass>
```

Comment: `Deserialize` has an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize-1(system-string-system-text-json-serialization-metadata-jsontypeinfo((-0)))) that takes a `JsonTypeInfo` - a customer converter could be registered to handle the lists.

Comment: What .,NET version are you using?  .NET 8?  .NET 7?  Something else?

Comment: @AndrewS From looking at the documentation of `JsonTypeInfo`, it sounds like that would only affect MyClass ("Metadata about the type to convert."). But I'll have to look into it.

Comment: @dbc I'm using .NET 7

Comment: Also, are you really using fields, or is `MyList` actually a property?  Because System.Text.Json doesn't serialize fields by default, you have to set [`JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.includefields?view=net-7.0), which you don't show in your question.

Comment: @dbc Yes you are right, my bad. I am using fields. I adjusted the question body accordingly.

Comment: @MarcMiller: Your edit and your comment say opposite things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [`JsonConverterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#sample-factory-pattern-converter) to automatically deserialize any properties or values **declared** as `IList<T>` to be `ObservableCollection<T>`.

First define the following converter factory:

```
public class IListAsObservableCollectionConverter : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => 
        typeToConvert.IsInterface && typeToConvert.IsGenericType && typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>);
    
    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(IListAsObservableCollectionConverterGeneric<>).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()))!;
    
    class IListAsObservableCollectionConverterGeneric<T> : JsonConverter<IList<T>>
    {
        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IList<T> value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options);
        public override IList<T>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObservableCollection<T>>(ref reader, options);
    }
}
```

Then deserialize using the following options:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new IListAsObservableCollectionConverter() },
    // Other options as required
    IncludeFields = true, // Required to serialize & deserialize public fields as well as properties.
};
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(json, options);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HYBTe9).

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much for taking the time. I will definitely have to look at your code in more detail to understand it, but it works perfectly, exactly what I was looking for!